# C++ For loop for two vector<string> and it's position to string

Tags: c++, for-loop, vector

```
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<string> data={"Hello World!","Goodbye World!"};
    for (vector<string>::iterator t=data.begin(); t!=data.end(); ++t) 
    {
        cout<<*t<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But I have two vectors and I need to convert their values to strings at certain position, like this:

```
vect = lineget3(nazev_souboru);
vect2 = lineget4(nazev_souboru);

for (a = vect.begin(); a < vect.end(); a++)
{
    string str = *a;
    string str2 = *b;?
}
```

And I dont know how to make str2 = *b (position of vect2).
How to make for loop for two vectors at certain position?

I cant make this

```
for (a = vect.begin(); a < vect.end(); a++)
{
    for (b = vect2.begin(); b < vect2.end(); b++)
    {
        string str = *a;
        string str2 = *b;
    }
}
```

I need only one loop for this. Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand the question, can you try to make it a bit clearer please?

Comment: So when you say vect and vect2, do you mean vect[0] and vect[1]? I don't understand lineget3 / lineget4. Are you extracting this from a file? What is nazev_souboru, is it a string?

Comment: An std::vector can be accessed using square brackets and its index so you could do: (for int i =0; i < vect.size() && i < vect2.size; i++)    string str = a[i]; string str2 = b[i];

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the vectors have the same length you can do:

```
for (auto a = vect.begin(), b = vect2.begin(); a < vect.end() && b < vect2.end(); ++a, ++b) {
    string str = *a;
    string str2 = *b;
}
```

If they have different size, <strike>it won't work</strike> the loop will not iterate over all elements of the larger vector.

Comment: Well, you can if you define a and b as being vector<string>::iterators!

Comment: They have same size.

Comment: `auto a = vect.cbegin();`
`auto b = vect2.cbegin();`
`for (;a != vect.cend() && b != vect2.cend(); a++, b++) {`
`string str = *a;`
`string str2 = *b;`
`}`
will work even when vectors have different sizes with number of iterations being equal to the size of smaller vector.

Comment: @JohnCvelth the code in the answer already "works" for differently sized vectors (it has `a < vect.end() && b < vect2.end()`). I dont understand why Thomas thinks for different sizes it wont work, but maybe he refers to the combinded loop only looping till the end of the smaller vector is reached without iterating over the rest of the longer vector. Anyhow, yours is more or less equivalent

Comment: @user463035818: Yes, with "it won't work" I mean: it will only iterate over all elements if vect and vect2 have same size.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`ranges::view::zip`](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/index.html#range-views) to combine a pair of ranges into one, and then use [structured bindings](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding) to split the elements

```
for (auto [a, b] : ranges::view::zip(vect, vect2))
{
    // use a and b
}
```